# GGPLOT is not loading anymore and crashed R Studio

Tags: r, ggplot2, rstudio

R studio was running fine until last week, when suddenly plots are not loading anymore, and R studio crashes when I try to compute a simple plot.
I up- and downgraded the R version and re installed R studio.
Does anyone know a solution?
Thanks a lot!

Comment: "Crash" means that the application actually stops (bomb icon+message etc.), not just an error message?  Try removing any `.RData` files you have lying around.  Can you run R successfully in the terminal or from the R Gui?

Comment: I cannot produce any plots anymore, neither with ggplot2 nor base R,

Comment: the Console keeps loading, and I can only continue when pushing the stop button in the console.
all the other code is running fine.

Comment: it's also not working in R (Quartz) anymore - stops responding after loading a graph

Comment: I would probably start by re-installing the current version of R and see if you can generate the most basic base-R graph (e.g. `plot(1:10, 1:10)`) from a clean/vanilla R session started in a terminal window (`R --vanilla`). Conceivably you could also try re-installing XQuartz (although I wouldn't try that unless necessary).

Comment: I tried the basic plot, but it is just keeping the terminal busy /: really cannot figure out the bug here

Comment: Have you done the reinstallations I suggested? (This does sound a little like your Quartz installation might be busted, although that's a little hard to imagine ...)

Comment: Yes I reinstalled Quartz, but I am not sure what to do with that, I'm quite new to R & co .. could I try something else or do sth in XQuartz to solve the problem?

Comment: It's going to be very hard to diagnose this. These kinds of problems are (presumably) very rare, as the standard installs of R work fine for most of the other 2 million R users ... if you are using a clean, up-to-date installation of R, then it has to be some weird/unusual problem with your particular setup. Is there any chance that you can get local/personalized debugging help from an expert?  (Can you plot to a file? e.g. does `pdf("tmpfile.pdf"); plot(1:10, 1:10); dev.off()` work and produce a PDF in your current working directory?)

Comment: Yes that produces the plot as pdf

Comment: Could it be a problem with my workspace?
I removed the .RData file an hour ago, but it reappeared.
and on starting R studio I get the following message:
[Workspace loaded from ~/folder_name/r_projects/project_name/.RData]

Comment: Conceivably, but unlikely.  In RStudio, you can (and should) go to the preferences/global tab (I think) and tell it (1) not to save the workspace and (2) not to restore the workspace. What happens if you `X11(); plot(1:10, 1:10)` ?

Comment: Produces the same plot, not as pdf but pops up

Comment: It's a bit difficult to see exactly whats going on. It would be helpful to provide screenshots, code, or anything that shows what led to that.

Answer (score 0):

Based on comments above:

- given that this is a fresh R install and `X11()` and `pdf()` both work OK, there must be something wrong with your Quartz/XQuartz installation. Besides re-installing, I don't know what to suggest ...
- As a workaround, you can use an X11 graphics device almost everywhere you would use a native Quartz graphics device. I *don't* think it's possible to tell RStudio to use X11 instead of Quartz (you could ask on an RStudio forum, or maybe someone else will have advice here), but you can start every RStudio session by opening a fresh X11 window (`X11()`), which R will then use for graphics instead of the built-in RStudio/quartz pane.

Not a perfect solution but maybe good enough to let you get some work done for now ... ?

Comment: Thanks a lot - I will try to figure something out! Thanks for the help!!